# Threadsafety question for Python collections in Scrapy Item Pipelines (using Twisted for concurrency)

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Scrapy has a notion of [Item Pipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that [concurrently process](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items) (via Twisted) items returned from a Scrapy [Spider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html). The following code example is provided for [filtering duplicate items](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter) (code copied below). How is it that the `set` can be used safely by concurrent calls to `process_item`? It seems that Scrapy invokes item pipelines [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/14612fc3d356c094703152809891b02eae8d1980/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L184).

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted and Scrapy are largely single-threaded.  Instead of preemptive multi-threading they provide concurrency by way of cooperative multi-tasking.  In a cooperative multi-tasking system, there is no preemption.  This means that a function like `process_item` above is perfectly safe to assume `self.ids_seen` will not change between its first and second to last lines.  Only this `process_item` method is running.  No other work can happen until `process_item` cooperatively gives up control.  It does this by raising an exception or return a value.  When this happens, control returns to its caller (or whatever the nearest `except` handler is).  That code then gets to run until it decides to give up control, and so on.  Eventually control is returned all the way to the Twisted `reactor` which picks another event to service by calling some application method.  Then the process repeats.